# Find applications that use the microphone with ADB

Tags: android, shell, adb, spyware

Google's voice assistant hasn't worked for some time because my phone's microphone seems to be used by another application.

With ADB, how do I know which applications are using the microphone?

Thank you!

**UPDATE:**

The output of **adb shell dumpsys audio** is as follows

```
MediaFocusControl dump time: 09:01:00

Audio Focus stack entries (last is top of stack):
mFocusStack:

mFocusStackForExternal:

No external focus policy



 Notify on duck:  true

 In ring or call: false


Stream volumes (device: index)
- STREAM_VOICE_CALL:
   Muted: false
   Min: 1
   Max: 10
   Current: 1 (earpiece): 10, 2 (speaker): 10, 4 (headset): 8, 20 (bt_sco_hs): 8, 80 (bt_a2dp): 8, 40000000 (default): 8
   Devices: earpiece
- STREAM_SYSTEM:
   Muted: false
   Min: 0
   Max: 15
   Current: 1 (earpiece): 12, 2 (speaker): 15, 4 (headset): 15, 20 (bt_sco_hs): 15, 80 (bt_a2dp): 15, 40000000 (default): 15
   Devices: speaker
- STREAM_RING:
   Muted: false
   Min: 0
   Max: 15
   Current: 1 (earpiece): 12, 2 (speaker): 15, 4 (headset): 15, 20 (bt_sco_hs): 15, 80 (bt_a2dp): 15, 40000000 (default): 15
   Devices: speaker
- STREAM_MUSIC:
   Muted: false
   Min: 0
   Max: 15
   Current: 2 (speaker): 8, 4 (headset): 8, 8 (headphone): 8, 20 (bt_sco_hs): 11, 80 (bt_a2dp): 13, 4000 (usb_device): 8, 20000000 (usb_device): 8, 40000000 (default): 11
   Devices: speaker
- STREAM_ALARM:
   Muted: false
   Min: 0
   Max: 15
   Current: 2 (speaker): 15, 40000000 (default): 12
   Devices: speaker
- STREAM_NOTIFICATION:
   Muted: false
   Min: 0
   Max: 15
   Current: 1 (earpiece): 12, 2 (speaker): 15, 4 (headset): 15, 20 (bt_sco_hs): 15, 80 (bt_a2dp): 15, 40000000 (default): 15
   Devices: speaker
- STREAM_BLUETOOTH_SCO:
   Muted: false
   Min: 0
   Max: 15
   Current: 1 (earpiece): 10, 20 (bt_sco_hs): 10, 80 (bt_a2dp): 13, 40000000 (default): 7
   Devices: earpiece
- STREAM_SYSTEM_ENFORCED:
   Muted: false
   Min: 0
   Max: 15
   Current: 1 (earpiece): 12, 2 (speaker): 15, 4 (headset): 15, 20 (bt_sco_hs): 15, 80 (bt_a2dp): 15, 40000000 (default): 15
   Devices: speaker
- STREAM_DTMF:
   Muted: false
   Min: 0
   Max: 15
   Current: 1 (earpiece): 12, 2 (speaker): 15, 4 (headset): 15, 20 (bt_sco_hs): 15, 80 (bt_a2dp): 15, 40000000 (default): 15
   Devices: speaker
- STREAM_TTS:
   Muted: false
   Min: 0
   Max: 15
   Current: 2 (speaker): 8, 4 (headset): 8, 8 (headphone): 8, 20 (bt_sco_hs): 11, 80 (bt_a2dp): 13, 4000 (usb_device): 8, 20000000 (usb_device): 8, 40000000 (default): 11
   Devices: speaker
- STREAM_ACCESSIBILITY:
   Muted: false
   Min: 0
   Max: 15
   Current: 2 (speaker): 8, 4 (headset): 8, 8 (headphone): 8, 20 (bt_sco_hs): 11, 80 (bt_a2dp): 13, 4000 (usb_device): 8, 20000000 (usb_device): 8, 40000000 (default): 11
   Devices: speaker

- mute affected streams = 0x2e

Ringer mode: 
- mode (internal) = NORMAL
- mode (external) = NORMAL
- ringer mode affected streams = 0x1a6 (STREAM_SYSTEM,STREAM_RING,STREAM_NOTIFICATION,STREAM_SYSTEM_ENFORCED,STREAM_DTMF)
- ringer mode muted streams = 0x0
- delegate = ZenModeHelper

Audio routes:
  mMainType=0x0
  mBluetoothName=null

Other state:
  mVolumeController=VolumeController(android.os.BinderProxy@962b52,mVisible=false)
  mSafeMediaVolumeState=SAFE_MEDIA_VOLUME_ACTIVE
  mSafeMediaVolumeIndex=80
  sIndependentA11yVolume=false
  mPendingVolumeCommand=null
  mMusicActiveMs=0
  UNSAFE_VOLUME_MUSIC_ACTIVE_MS_MAX=72000000
  mMcc=222
  mCameraSoundForced=false
  mHasVibrator=true
  mVolumePolicy=VolumePolicy[volumeDownToEnterSilent=false,volumeUpToExitSilent=true,doNotDisturbWhenSilent=true,vibrateToSilentDebounce=400]
  mAvrcpAbsVolSupported=false

Audio policies:

PlaybackActivityMonitor dump time: 09:01:00
  ID:23 -- type:android.media.SoundPool -- u/pid:1000/1431 -- state:idle -- attr:AudioAttributes: usage=6 content=4 flags=0x0 tags= bundle=null
  ID:39 -- type:android.media.SoundPool -- u/pid:10028/2089 -- state:idle -- attr:AudioAttributes: usage=13 content=4 flags=0x0 tags= bundle=null
  ID:31015 -- type:android.media.MediaPlayer -- u/pid:10028/2089 -- state:stopped -- attr:AudioAttributes: usage=5 content=4 flags=0x0 tags= bundle=null
  ID:15 -- type:android.media.SoundPool -- u/pid:1000/1431 -- state:idle -- attr:AudioAttributes: usage=13 content=4 flags=0x0 tags= bundle=null
  ID:31 -- type:android.media.SoundPool -- u/pid:10028/2089 -- state:idle -- attr:AudioAttributes: usage=13 content=4 flags=0x0 tags= bundle=null
  ID:31007 -- type:android.media.MediaPlayer -- u/pid:1000/1431 -- state:stopped -- attr:AudioAttributes: usage=13 content=4 flags=0x0 tags= bundle=null

  ducked players:

  muted player piids:

RecordActivityMonitor dump time: 09:01:00
  session:5065 -- source:VOICE_COMMUNICATION -- uid:10132 -- patch:9 -- pack:com.whatsapp -- format client=1ch 16000Hz ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, dev=1ch 16000Hz ENCODING_PCM_16BIT

Audio Mode:
HwAudioService:DEBUG =false
mIsHuaweiSafeMediaConfig =true
mSecurityVolumeIndex =8
LOUD_VOICE_MODE_SUPPORT=false
Lound Voice State:
HW_SOUND_TRIGGER_SUPPORT=false
mSoundTriggerStatus=0
mad=on:
wakeup=on:
HW_KARAOKE_EFFECT_ENABLED=true
DTS_SOUND_EFFECTS_SUPPORT=false
mDtsStatus=0
Dts State:
DTS_MODE_PRESTATE:unknown
HS_NO_CHARGE_ON:
isCallForeground=true
DUAL_SMARTPA_SUPPORT=false
SPK_RCV_STEREO_SUPPORT=false
mSpkRcvStereoStatus=-1
mLowlatencyUidsMap={}
mVoipOptimizeInGameMode =false
```

I don't know, but it seems that the microphone is not in use by any application, or maybe I am wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using this command :

```
adb shell dumpsys audio
```

In the output look under `Audio Focus stack entries (last is top of stack)`.It will show the the package name of the app using microphone

Example (When I am using microphone in whatsapp) the output was:

```
 source:android.os.BinderProxy@829ac54 -- pack: com.whatsapp -- client: android.media.AudioManager@d13214cX.4K0@e5a922d -- gain: GAIN_TRANSIENT -- flags:  -- loss: none -- notified: true -- uid: 10165 -- attr: AudioAttributes: usage=USAGE_MEDIA content=CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC flags=0x800 tags= bundle=null -- sdk:30
```

Comment: If the stack entries is empty then i think there's no app using microphone at that moment.

Comment: I may not be a cybersecurity expert, but is there any vague possibility that this is due to spyware? if so, what other checks can I do to identify it?

Comment: to be safe you can scan ur device with any anti virus app. i don't think this is a spyware , coz i also have the same error for my front camera, the error says camera is already in use . even factory reset didn't fix it . if it was a spyware it should have been gone in the reset.

Comment: In my case the hard reset works, but after a few days, even if I don't install any application except whatsapp, the problem reappears. I think having to reset the phone at least twice a week is sheer madness, so I would have liked to know what and who is using the phone's microphone without my consent.